# Continue after XCUITest

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, xcode-ui-testing

Instruments(automator) is no longer a thing for Xcode 8.x, so I'm looking for a way to automate input with XCUITests.  I'm able to get the input I want, but then the test succeeds and the app exits in the simulator.  Is there any way to run the script and then continue to an idle state rather than quitting?

Comment: I think you can put a breakpoint on the last line of the test your run, then as long as it stays on the breakpoint you should be able to use the app.

Comment: That does work for now. I'd like to know what people are using for automation now that instruments is out the door.

Comment: Xcode has a new UI tests framework, Joe Masilotti has done a lot of work providing resources and references on it. Have you not heard of this, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using uitesting in Xcode.  However it behaves a little differently.  I want to be able to input automatically and continue without the app terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Each XCTest file has a setup and a teardown method.

The template files come with an `XCUIApplication().launch()` in the setup method.  Try wrapping that in an if statement like so:

```
if XCUIApplication().exists {
//do nothing
} else {
  XCUIApplication().launch()
}
```

Now when you run this suite of tests, it will only launch the app if its not already on screen, but if you already ran a test and the app is still running it will just go to the next one.